# Swipe but no Click

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have a transparent window which I want to use to capture Swipes.

Setting `setAcceptTouchEvents=True` and `setIgnoreMouseEvents=false` seems also to ignore Swipes. Only mouse entered or leave events are registered.

What I need is the window to catch the swipes, but let clicks go through.

I would appreciate if somebody has any idea how I could realize that? (sandboxed though)

Comment: Try to set acceptsFirstResponder to YES. The method - (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event; should get called

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your view has the first responder, and that you're actually overriding the right method.

You should override the `swipeWithEvent:` method, like mentioned before.

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work. I should be clear: The clicks that are meant to go through the transparent window should hit the desktop/dock, not another view or window of my application.

Comment: I tried it doing this:

 - (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event{ NSLog(@"Swipe!"); }
 
 -(BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder{ return TRUE; }